# gcc with -Wformat option prints warning for const unsigned char

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-warnings

Test Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    char buf[10];

    char c[] = "%i";
    unsigned char uc[] = "%i";
    const char cc[] = "%i";
    const unsigned char cuc[] = "%i";
    const unsigned char *cucp = "%i";

    sprintf(buf, (char *)c, 1);
    sprintf(buf, (char *)uc, 1);
    sprintf(buf, (char *)cc, 1);
    sprintf(buf, (char *)cuc, 1);
    sprintf(buf, (char *)cucp, 1);

    return 0;
}
```

Compile:

```
gcc -Wformat -o test test.c
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:16:26: warning: format is a wide character string [-Wformat=]
    sprintf(buf, (char *)cuc, 1);
                         ^
```

> Why do I get a warning for *const unsigned char* but not for the other types?

Tested with gcc 5.4.0 and some cross gcc 4.3.2.
The explanation might include in which segments the different data types are stored, but I'm quite surprised.

Comment: I don't see a warning with clang. Looks like a GCC issue to me.

Comment: @PaulFloyd,  You need to turn on the warnings.  'clang' uses 'gcc', so the available warnings are (mostly) the same.  Suggest: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11`   this will result in 4 warnings.  Two of those warnings are about the unused parameters `argc` and `argv`  Then a warning about this line: `const unsigned char *cucp = "%i";`  (pointer targets in initialization differ in signedness)  then a warning about this line: `sprintf(buf, (char *)cuc, 1);` (format is a wide character string)

Comment: cont: So your warning (you really need to enable more warnings) The code is declaring a unsigned char but the result is being cast to signed char in the call to sprintf().  In any case, referencing a 'format string' is a security risk.  Best to place the 'format string' right in the parameter

Comment: Good idea the test with another compiler. But I don't think clang uses gcc and I couldn't reproduce the warning with clang. Also looks like a gcc issue to me. I've submitted a [bug report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=84258).

Comment: @user3629249 I'm not sure what you mean by "'clang' uses 'gcc'". Maybe you are referring to Apple's llvm GCC compiler which uses GCC as front end. Regular llvm/clang uses more or less compatible command line switches, but the similarity ends there. clang 5 on compiler explorer produces 9 warnings with -Weverything but no warning about wide character strings.

Answer (score 1):

It's now a confimred gcc [bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=84258) and should be fixed soon.

BTW: It was introduced 2000-09-24.